# de-grouping iTerm2 windows

Tags: window-manager, iterm

Activating iTerm2's "hotkey window" (i.e. drop-down console) also brings to front all other iTerm2 windows. Is there a way to avoid this, making OS X treat each window as a separate application rather than as a group of windows?

Aside: Deactivating/hiding the hotkey window again makes it retain focus (only) if the previously focused window was also an iTerm window, otherwise hiding the drop-down console correctly refocuses the previous window. Seems like that might be related to the issue above.